# How to disable the first fire of the dispatch source timer

Tags: ios, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I am using Dispatch source timer.

```
dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), interval, leeway);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
dispatch_resume(timer);
```

However, I find that the block is called almost immediately after the code above is run over. After that the timer fires every interval. 
My question is how to disable the first fire?

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `dispatch_source_set_timer` is the time when the timer should fire for the first time. You're setting it to `dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0)`, i.e. "now".

To make it fire for the first time after some interval, pass `dispatch_walltime(NULL, interval)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when dispatch time is in past or is now. Check your dispatch time.